# How to append values to a form in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, svelte, sveltekit

So, I am using the default behavior in sveltekit, in which we use html forms to submit data to backend, but there is also a file upload that uses ajax (fetch api) to upload image to server and get its file name, now I want to append these names to the html form state in somehow, is this possible or should I move to full state managed forms instead?

here is my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';
    import type { ActionData } from './$types';
    let input: HTMLInputElement;
    let container;
    let images: string[] = [];
    let placeholder;
    let showImage = false;
    let files: Blob[] = [];
    let form: ActionData;

    const uploadImage = async (file: Blob) => {
        let formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('image', file);
        const res = await fetch('/api/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formdata
        });
        const resp = await res.json();
        console.log({ resp });
    };

    const onChange = async () => {
        const imgFiles = input.files;
        if (imgFiles) {
            for (let i = 0; i < imgFiles.length; i++) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
                    if (typeof reader.result == 'string') {
                        images = [...images, reader.result];
                        // upload the reader result to backend
                    }
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(imgFiles[i]);
                files = [...files, imgFiles[i]];
                await uploadImage(imgFiles[i]);
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<form
    use:enhance
    class="flex rounded-lg shadow-lg my-10 sm:w-1/2 md:w-2/4 flex-col mx-auto p-2 sm:p-6"
    method="post"
    action="/products/add"
>
    {#if form && form.success}
        <p class="">Product Added Sucessfully</p>
    {/if}
    <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold">Add a product / service</h2>
    <div class="my-4">
        <label for="prodSer">Is this a product or a service?</label>
        <select name="type">
            <option value="product">Product</option>
            <option value="service">Service</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input class="basicInput" name="name" placeholder="Name of your product" />
    <textarea
        class="textArea"
        rows={5}
        name="description"
        placeholder="Write a description about it"
    />
    <div class="h-full">
        <h4>Images</h4>
        <label for="imagePicker">Choose images</label>
        <input
            multiple
            bind:this={input}
            on:change={onChange}
            id="imagePicker"
            name="productImages"
            type="file"
            placeholder="Upload media"
        />
        <div class="flex h-full flex-row my-4 mx-2">
            {#if images.length > 0}
                {#each images as image}
                    <div class="h-64 mx-2">
                        <img class="h-64" src={image} />
                        <button class="">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                {/each}
            {/if}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="currency">Currency</label>
        <select id="currency" name="currency">
            <option value="Rs.">Rupees</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
        <input class="basicInput halfInput" min={0} name="mrp" placeholder="MRP" type="number" />
        <input class="basicInput halfInput" min={0} name="price" placeholder="Price" type="price" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
        <input class="basicInput halfInput" min={0} name="gst" placeholder="GST %" type="number" />
        <input class="basicInput halfInput" min={0} name="cess" placeholder="Cess %" type="price" />
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
        <label class="text-sm text-gray-600" for="taxIncl">Price is Inclusive of tax?</label>
        <input id="taxIncl" type="checkbox" name="includeTax" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="basicInput" name="unit" placeholder="Unit" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="basicInput" name="hsn" placeholder="HSN/SAC" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="basicInput" name="stock" placeholder="Opening Stock" type="number" />
    </div>

    <input
        class="my-2 sm:my-4 sm:w-1/2 hover:cursor-pointer text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-full text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
        type="submit"
        value="Add"
    />
</form>

<style>
    .basicInput {
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .textArea {
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .halfInput {
        width: 49%;
    }
    select {
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to add the input to the form programmatically, you could [call the action programmatically with `fetch`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-custom-event-listener) instead

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue and might have a solution.

I use a component called `Form` which looks like this (using vanilla JS with JSDoc notation):

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    /** @type {string} */
    export let name;

    /** @type {string} */
    export let method = 'POST';

    /** @type {string | null} */
    export let action = null;

    /** @type {Object} */
    export let attributes = {};

    /** @type {string | null} */
    export let _class = null;

    /** @type {string | null} */
    export let autocomplete = 'off';

    /** @type {boolean} */
    export let do_update = true;

    /** @type {function | null} */
    export let manipulation = null;

    /** @param {any} event */
    function handleResult(event) {
        dispatch('post_result', event);
    }
</script>

<form
    {name}
    {method}
    {action}
    id={name}
    class={_class}
    {autocomplete}
    {...attributes}
    use:enhance={({ data }) => {
        if (manipulation) manipulation(data);
        return async ({ result, update }) => {
            if (do_update) update();
            handleResult(result);
        };
    }}
>
    <slot />
</form>
```

You'll note the variable `manipulation` which is used during the `use:enhance` callback. It references a function which directly accesses and manipulates the form's data. I suppose this works thanks to the way JavaScript references/mutates objects. In a component or page, I can manipulate the form data like so:

```
<script>
    /** @param {FormData} data */
    function manipulateForm(data) {
        value = 'myvalue' // Provide your values here
        data.set('set_field', value);
        data.delete('delete_field');
        // ...and so on
    }
</script>

<Form {name} manipulation={manipulateForm}>
```

When `request.formData()` is called, it returns the manipulated form data.